# Form css changes in different browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in the website http://helloiwant.com/demo.html
It is done with bootstrap. However when I view it on either safari or firefox, it doesn't show it properly but it always shows it properly on chrome. My guess is something to do with css but I cannot figure out the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome, either. The text is in white, completely unreadable against a light gray background.

Comment: That is weird. It is working on chrome on my laptop. I even cleared the cache and history. It is still working correctly. Anyone know why it is doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code of the webpage, if everything being white is the problem you have to change color and border-color in the css to black(#000) (or the color you want) since everything is white/(#fff).

But it seems like you are using an external source for the bootstrap css, so you should go to the official site and download [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and put it on your server. Remember to customize it to fit the style you are going for, or edit it manually after downloading it.

Or you can create an extra css file that loads after the boostrap css, and just add overrides for the colors.

I have no idea why it works for you in Chrome, in my experience Chrome always finds a way to load outdated css files, try to disable cache in the developer tools. 
 
[How to disable cache in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development) <-Check answer here

Comment: I figured out the problem. When I deleted the bootstrap JS cdn link from my code, it now shows it as normal. My guess is that my js code and the bootstrap js overlapped at somepoint.About the chrome, I forgot to delete the cache and refresh it in chrome. My bad about that. Thank you for your help.